Sort Elements behavior
As I am still working on how to make faces from curves, adding more faces and more curves, I encountered some strange behavior of the Sort Elements nodes, I don't see what I did wrong. Is this a bug or, as usual, a misunderstanding of how it works? In this .blend, I rotate a plane, I use a Mesh to Points on the faces, I cancel the rotation with a Set Position then I Sort the elements on X and on Y, but the indexes always behave as if I rotated them... Could you help me solve this problem?


Thank you for your help.
The blend:


These are rounding errors. If you rotate the grid back and forth in this way, the positions are slightly changed and not (as you would expect) in exactly the same position. However, the Node Sort Elements is very precise here.

@quellenform Thank you, I will try to see if there is a walk around...

I suppose you could broaden the definition of equality for the final X and Y positions, in one way or another:   https://imgur.com/a/3zn1fq9.. but no, that's still fraught, it  presumably falls back on index order, or something not guaranteed.

@RobinBetts Thank you, this is certainly the simplest solution. Thanks again.

@RobinBetts You stepped the value at 0.006 does it mean that the Weight socket of the Sort Element is rounded at 0.005?

Just a stupid question: Why don't you capture the positions before you change them (and reset them again) with Capture Attribute and sort these values? Presumably the example shown is a simplified version of what you actually want to do, but if you tell us a little more about it, there may be other solutions....

@quellenform You are right this is stupid, you already answer this question. I am still working on that blender.stackexchange.com/questions/317094/planes-on-curves adding more plan and more curves. The  Sort Element is a powerful nodes in order to simplify a node tree. I will edit my post, and try to find other solutions...

Uh, no! ...I meant that my question is stupid, not yours! ;-)

Actually, I meant this: https://i.sstatic.net/bZLAi78U.png ...Since the position in your example should not actually change (but does in reality due to rounding errors), I simply use the original position as the sorting criterion here. However, since I don't know the real use case, my suggestion could also be complete nonsense.

Thanks to quellenform and Robin Betts for your solutions, another one is to add a Map Range on Stepped linear before each Sort Elements:

And the .blend:

Edit:
As said qellenform I should have post my original .blend, that is a version with a solution by Robin Betts:


.. to be treated with caution. Mine was  not a general solution, but one tuned to your file (hence the .006). As @quellenform suggests, IMO, it would be better to avoid fine floating point assessments of equality altogether. If you have an available ground truth (here, P before rotations, but could be something else in general) stash it and stick with it if you can.

@RobinBetts You are right to remind it, but in this case I can't use the quellenform solution...
